# Django rest framework saving seralizer with foregin key

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Quick question I am trying to save model and have following setup

models.py

```
class Example1(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=90, null=True, blank=True)

class Example2(models.Model):
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=90, null=True, blank=True)
    example1 = models.ForeignKey(Example1, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='example1_example2')
```

serializers.py

```
class Example1Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Example1.objects.create(**validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = Example1
        fields = ['id', 'field1']

class Example2Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Example2.objects.create(**validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = Example2
        fields = ['id', 'example1', 'field2']
```

upon initiating following code

```
new_example1 = Example1Serializer(data=JSONEXAMPLE1DATA)
if new_example1.is_valid():
    new_example1.save()

    **works well**
```

---

```
JSONEXAMPLE2DATA = {
    'field2' = 'test',
    'example1' = new_example1.data['id']
}

new_example2 = Example2Serializer(data=JSONEXAMPLE2DATA)
if new_example2.is_valid():
    new_example2.save()

**doesnt work gives must be a "Example1" instance**
```

upon changing `JSONEXAMPLE2DATA` to

```
JSONEXAMPLE2DATA = {
    'field2' = 'test',
    'example1' = new_example1
}
```

gives `Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received Example1Serializer.`

is setup wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this:

```py
JSONEXAMPLE2DATA = {
    'field2' = 'test',
    'example1' = new_example1.data['id']
}
```

Use this:

```py
JSONEXAMPLE2DATA = {
    'field2' = 'test',
    'example1' = Example1.objects.get(id=new_example1.data['id'])
}
```

Hope this will work ;)

Comment: I figured that would work but very unefficient to get object we just saved only for foreign key, much easier just to use model directly

Comment: arent serializer supposed to make handling models easier?

Comment: Exactly that is more efficient if you use `Model` directly. The solution described above is only to solve your error.

Comment: @yedodi2781 have a look at this [rest_framework serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializers) docs. It fully explains the purpose of serializers.